# In "Prophecy", when going onto a space that has a villain on it, are you required to fight it?

Tags: untagged

A few days ago, I played the RPG "Prophecy" for the first time. While playing, we ran across a question that the experienced player among us did not know, and looking through the rules didn't give any answers (although it is of course possible we just missed it).

After a player has flipped over an "Adventure" card on a space, and a monster / villain is revealed - like, say, a Flock of Harpies - the player then has to fight this monster. If they lose, on the next turn they can then move away from the space with the monster (or of course fight it again).

After the player has moved away from this revealed monster, let's say another player then moves to the spot with this monster.
**Are they then required to fight this monster, seeing as how they have just landed on the spot with a revealed monster, or can they *choose* whether they want to fight or not?**

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is yes, if you end your movement on a space with a revealed monster on it you must fight it.

This is set out in [the rules](https://images-cdn.zmangames.com/us-east-1/filer_public/27/ee/27eec60f-b589-4dde-8e78-88afa4a3f99e/zm7380_prophecy_basic_rules.pdf), under **Adventure Cards**, the two parts that govern this are the following:

> You are always affected by the Adventure cards located in the space where you end your movement.

and

> If you encounter a Creature you must battle it (unlike using an Opportunity,
>   fighting a Creature is mandatory).